# Is "Nachts weinen die Soldaten" a hommage to "Es ist an der Zeit" or to "Green Fields of France"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Today I listened to "Nachts weinen die Soldaten" (At night the soldiers are crying) by Saltatio Mortis. And I was reminded of "Es ist an der Zeit" (It's about time) by Hannes Wader. So my question would be if it is a knowing hommage or just a coincidence. Does anybody know what the songwriter says about this?

To clear up where I see parallels I would like to describe both songs a bit.

First "Es ist an der Zeit": It is a german interpretation of "Green Fields of France" by Eric bogle. The music is the same, the text was written by Hannes Wader and it was originally interpreted by himself. Since the text is close to the original it also could be that "Green Fields of France" was more of the source then "Es ist an der Zeit".

"Nachts weinen die Soldaten" is a song by the german medieval-rock-band Saltatio Mortis.

Both talk about the life and in fact death of a soldier in the first World War.

Then there are a few reasons where I think "Es ist an der Zeit" is close to "Nachts weinen die Soldaten".

- Both talk about the cross of that soldier. In "Es ist an der Zeit" it is then "Auf deinem Kreuz finde ich, toter Soldat, - deinen Namen nicht nur Ziffern und jemand hat - die Zahl 1916 gemalt" (On your cross, dead soldier, I don't find your name, but only numbers and somebody has painted the number 1916 on it) , while Saltatio Mortis sings "trägt nicht mal deinen Namen, - 1916 hat wer drauf gemalt." (it not even shows your name, 1916 somebody has painted on).
- Also the question "Warst du verliebt - und wer hat dich vermisst?" (Were you in love, and who was missing you) in "Nachts weinen die Soldaten" reminds a bit of "Hast du, toter Soldat, mal ein Mädchen geliebt?" (Have you, dead soldier, loved a girl before?), even though Hannes Wader answers it that it is not likely because love can only live in peace.

The whole theme, the whole Idea seems so close to the other song, but of course this could also be a coincidence. While the song of Hannes Wader is more harsh, it is also at the end more hopeful.